# Ajax call to Server PHP only sometimes print back request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

When I load my index.html site, it would sometimes return the Ajax which would call the php on server to print the result of my dynamic page. Why does it only sometimes work when I go to the address bar and press enter or refresh?

This is the site [Click Here!](http://cis-linux2.temple.edu/~tud15304/secretSanta/)

This has been bothering me for sometime now.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Christmas- 2014: Secret Santa</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styleSheet.css">
  <link rel="icon" type="icon" href="images/favicon.ico">

  <script>
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      //code for IE7, Firefox and everything new....
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
      //for the old things
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }




    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("mainDynamic").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
      }





      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#export_excel_button").click(function(e) {

          window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + $('#userTable').html());
          e.preventDefault();
        });

      });


    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "resourceLines.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  </script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  </script>
</head>

<body id='mainBody'>
  <img class="Banner" src="images/Banner.JPG" alt="Banner" width="886" height="187">
  <section>
    <div id='mainDynamic'>


    </div>
    <article class='leftSide'>
      <div class="Presentations">
        <h1>Important Information</h1>
        <b>WebSite Scheme:</b>
        <br>
        <p>The Purpose of this is to have computer generated randomization of the "Secret Santa gifting". All wish list can be made online and will be automatically uploaded to the server. Then, I will run the program to randomly pair you then display the
          wish list to whom you'll be a secret Santa to.</p>

        <p>So things to do:
          <p>
            <ul>
              <li>Make an account</li>
              <li>Build your wish list</li>
            </ul>
            <p><b>WARNING</b>: It is important that you make only ONE! account for yourself.
              <p>

                <p>
                  <b>Gifting Criteria:</b>
                  <br>

                  <ul>
                    <li><b>Amount of Gifts-</b> Each person should have at least 3 gifts for the gift-er to chose from</li>
                    <li><b>Price of Total Gifts-</b> $50</li>
                    <li>Total Amount of gifts you buy for the person must be close to equal or more than $50</li>
                  </ul>
                  <br>
                  <b>Commonly Asked Questions</b>
                  <ul>
                    <li>Can we list multiple gifts on our wish list to add up to the <b>MAX</b> dollar amount? Yes, if there are multiple low priced items, you will have to chose to buy enough gifts to add up to the total amount.</li>
                  </ul>
                </p>
      </div>
    </article>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are you not allowed to use the JQuery ajax methods?

Comment: Might have to do with the document not being loaded at that point yet. Do you get any errors? Have you tried moving your javascript code to the bottom of the page, right before the closing `<body>` tag?

Comment: Plus the jQuery lib should be included before you actually use it. See the error in the console.

Comment: It's really strange to place `$(document).ready` inside an ajax callback. And furthermore, if you want to use jQuery, always load it firstly.

Comment: I am actually allowed to use anything. What is the best way to fetch this data? I am not very good with Jquery and ajax sadly.

Answer (score 1):

I checked your site and suggestions are below:

1. The error is that when you use `$(document).ready(function() {...}` (it's inside your xmlhttprequest), the jQuery is not loaded. So, it results to the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`.
2. Load jQuery first and your error won't occur again.
3. If you use jQuery, why not use `$.ajax`? jQuery do the browser compatiable for you!

Code below:

```
 <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script> 
$(function() { // execute after dom loaded
    $.ajax({
        url: 'resourceLines.php'
    }).done(function(res) {
        // do whatever you like
    });
});
</script>
```